# Grouping pandas dataframe by month, week, day behave differently

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a series of events written inside a data-frame. I can group by different time-periods.

First I was doing it daily and I changed it to monthly and the behavior is different. when you iterate through the groups:

```
grouped = df.groupby(by=pd.Grouper(key="date_GMT",freq="M"))
for k, grp in grouped:
    print(k)
```

In the case of the day as the frequency the k in the iteration is always the beginning of the day, while in the case of week, month it is the end. I got a future leak due to this. What is the best way to solve it in standardized way?

Comment: freq="MS" gives the start dates of the months

Comment: @Muhammadhassan Thank you!